# Invalid hooks calls in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a problem cause I'm getting the `userAccess` from redux. I need to identify if it is admin or not.
My problem is that its not inside a hook so I can't get the redux value.

here's my code below

**Code**

```
 import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    const role = useSelector((state) => state.role);
    
    export default [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Leaders',
        url: `/leaders`,
        userAccess: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Users',
        url: `/users`,
        userAccess: role === 'Admin',
      },
    ];
```

**Code**

```
const Menu = ({ items, isCollapseMenu }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {items.map(
        (item) =>
          item.userAccess && (
            <MenuItem
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              icon={item.icon}
              text={item.text}
              shortText={item.shortText}
              url={item.url}
              submenu={item.submenu}
              isCollapseMenu={isCollapseMenu}
            />
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the `useSelector` hook can't be used on it's own outside a React functional component or custom React hook.

I suggest you configure your exported menu items to either set `userAccess` to a boolean or role value, and access your redux state in the `Menu` component.

Menu items

```
export default [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Leaders',
    url: `/leaders`,
    userAccess: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Users',
    url: `/users`,
    userAccess: 'Admin',
  },
];
```

Menu

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const checkAccess = (access, role) => {
  if (typeof access === 'string') {
    return role === access;
  };
  return access;
};

const Menu = ({ items, isCollapseMenu }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const role = useSelector((state) => state.role);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {items.map(
        (item) =>
          checkAccess(item.userAccess, role) && (
            <MenuItem
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              icon={item.icon}
              text={item.text}
              shortText={item.shortText}
              url={item.url}
              submenu={item.submenu}
              isCollapseMenu={isCollapseMenu}
            />
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you also do this kind of  thing on frontend? What is approach on this kind of thing? Thanks

Comment: @Joseph React is (*mostly*) a frontend UI framework, so I guess the answer is, yes? I'm not really sure what you are asking for though. Role-based access?

Comment: Yes. Do you also store token and role on localstorage? Is it safe?

Comment: It is convenient.

Comment: @Joseph Sure, you can store an auth token (and role) or similar in the frontend, and send token with subsequent requests to your backend APIs, to be validated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `useSelector()` in a component or in another hook. You can create a custom hook (`useRoles`) that returns the array of roles, and use it in the component:

```
const useRoles = () => {
  const role = useSelector((state) => state.role);

  return [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Leaders',
      url: `/leaders`,
      userAccess: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Users',
      url: `/users`,
      userAccess: role === 'Admin',
    },
  ];
};
```

Get the `items` from the `useRoles` hook:

```
const Menu = ({ isCollapseMenu }) => {
  const items = useRoles();
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {items.map(
        (item) =>
          item.userAccess && (
            <MenuItem
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              icon={item.icon}
              text={item.text}
              shortText={item.shortText}
              url={item.url}
              submenu={item.submenu}
              isCollapseMenu={isCollapseMenu}
            />
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```